# Pulling javascript from tumblr with specified username

Tags: javascript, tumblr

I am trying to get a fairly simple bit of code to work. The essence of it is just to take user input, append it on to a source URL, and then use a script to display the appropriate tumblr feed.

I have spent some time on this, and I can't get my head around how javascript works enough to do something like this.

This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        Tumblr Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src= username + ".tumblr.com/js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a sample URL you expect to work? Trying random usernames gets 404s for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the JS file that is on username.tumblr.com uses `document.write`, I think it'd be better to just load the actual url of the user in an iframe, as this wouldn't require you to refresh the page, while creating a mini page inside your page.

This won't work on the snippet tool here or on JSFiddle, but I've tested it on a web server:

```
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    function getUN() {
      var username = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value;
      document.getElementById("tumblrframe").src = "http://" + username + ".tumblr.com";

    }
  </script>

  Tumblr Username:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="getUN()">Submit</button>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <iframe id="tumblrframe" width="80%" height="600px"></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that JavaScript works, is you need an event to attach the running of your code. In your case, the form's `submit` event. Additionally, you cannot compute values within the HTML as you're attempting; you'll need code to manipulate the HTML (the DOM). Here's a sample of how you can do it:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form onSubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
        Tumblr Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script id="theScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
      function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Keep the form from actually submitting
        var username = document.querySelector('[name="username"]').value;
        document.getElementById('theScript').src = username + '.tumblr.com/js';
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```